# c++ open file not working

Tags: c++, file-io

I am working on creating a hash table and I am having problems with opening a file. The files "PeriodicTableElements.txt" and "formulas.txt" are both in the same directory. However when I run the following code, I get an error that I am unable to open formulas.txt.

```
ifstream input1;
input1.open("PeriodicTableElements.txt");
if(input1.fail())
{
    cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    exit(0);
}
input1.close();

ifstream file_input1;
file_input1.open("formulas.txt");
if(file_input1.fail())
{
    cout << "Unable to open the file formulas.txt." << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    exit(0);
}
```

I don't understand why the first one would work, but the second one fails xD.

Comment: Might be a long shot, but have you checked the permissions on `formulas.txt`? You'll get an error if you don't have permission to read it.

Comment: Does that file exist? Is everything spelled right? Do you have permission to read and write that file? The code looks fine so it's probably some issue with your environment.

Comment: I found the answer, it was a problem with the name of the file. For some reason when I downloaded it from my teacher it was named "formulas.txt.txt"

Answer (score 0):

The answer was pretty simple, for some reason the formulas.txt file was saved as formulas.txt and known file extensions aren't being shown. So the real file name was formulas.txt.txt which makes sense why it wasn't opening. It's just weird that it would download that way when it was directly from my teacher.